# How docker manages machine configuration

Tags: docker

This might be a stupid question, but a question asked in a recent interview left me pondering about how docker manages the machine configuration. When I said docker makes it possible to have the same environment for your application in production, staging and development, they asked me this question:

> If the production configuration for your application is something like 64GB ram, 1TB ssd hard drive and stuff like that, and your development configuration is a much meagre 8GB RAM, 512 GB normal hard disk, how does docker makes the environment similar?

I was dumbstruck!

Answer (score 0):

Docker allows you to limit resources to each Container (at least it is possible now).
But anyway, the resources are up to different circumstances and they could change. There is no reason to have a static hardware configuration for your apps.

The point of docker is to make **software** environment consistent not the **hardware** one. Docker does not want to keep you from having **Vertical Scaling**. Without docker you have vertical scaling, but by using docker you expand your ability to have horizontal scaling at the same time.

The whole question they asked is wrong. If you had a host of 10GB of ram and a container and it was stock on 8GB of ram, and for example your visitors where low and you had to scale down the host to 5GB of ram to lower your costs, then guess what, you could not. Why? because you container is stock on 8GB and it would crash if the real ram is lower than that (Actually in newer docker versions you set the maximum and it is not static i.e. it is not occupied the moment the container runs.)

Remember, docker is about have Horiz and Vertz and the same time!